# Parallel Period filter (MDX)

Tags: sql-server, sql

Si tenemos el siguiente query en el cubo **`[Adventure Works]`** de la BD `AdventureWorksDW2014`:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Previo] AS
( [Date].[Calendar].currentmember.PrevMember,[Measures].[Customer Count]) 
MEMBER [Measures].[Paralelo] AS 
(ParallelPeriod([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year], 1,  
[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember), [Measures].[Customer Count]) 
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Previo], [Measures].[Paralelo],   
[Measures].[Customer Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[12], [Date].
[Calendar].[Month].&[2011]&[12], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[12],
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[11], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].& 
[2011]&[11], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[11],  
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[10], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].& 
[2011]&[10], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[10] }) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Adventure Works])
```

Produce el siguiente resultado:

> ```
>           Previo  Paralelo    Cuenta de Clientes
>
> CY 2010   (null)  (null)      14
> CY 2011   14      14          651
> CY 2012   2216    2216        988
> ```

Se observa que por año, se suma la Medida Natural de los meses que se han filtrado.

Pero no sucede lo mismo con las Medidas Calculadas, las cuales se suman por el año completo sin tomar en cuenta los meses filtrados.
¿Cómo logramos filtrar las medidas calculadas (Previo y Paralelo)?

Por otro lado, Cuando se involucra otro siguiente nivel de la jerarquía, como el mes en el query siguiente:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Previo] AS 
([Date].[Calendar].currentmember.PrevMember,[Measures].[Customer Count]) 
MEMBER [Measures].[Paralelo] AS (ParallelPeriod([Date].[Calendar]. 
[Calendar Year], 1,  [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember), [Measures].  
[Customer Count]) 
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Paralelo], [Measures].[Previo],   
[Measures].[Customer Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Calendar].[Month].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[12], [Date]. 
[Calendar].[Month].&[2011]&[12], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[12], 
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[11], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&
[2011]&[11], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[11], 
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2010]&[10], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].& 
[2011]&[10], [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2012]&[10]}) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Adventure Works] )
```

Produce el siguiente resultado:

> ```
>                 [Paralelo]    [Previo]    [Cuenta de Clientes]
> December 2010   (null)        (null)      14
> October 2011    (null)        185         221
> November 2011   (null)        221         208
> December 2011   14            208         222
> October 2012    221           269         313
> November 2012   208           313         324
> December 2012   222           324         354
> ```

Se observa que las medidas calculadas SI se calculan correctamente involucrando los filtros de meses.